# Web Clipboard Icon

Tags: google-drive

I am working in google Docs and no longer have a web clipboard icon in the toolbar. In the past I always had it which enabled me to copy and paste within the google document I was working on and from other google documents I had created before. How do I get this webclipboard icon back on my toolbar?

Comment: Have you tried to copy/paste the normal way? Ctrl C --> Ctrl V

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in Google setting to get the icon back on the toolbar. What you can do is go to `Edit` > `WebClipboard`, and this will show you the items you have stored.